# Mathf.PingPong equivalent in Java

Tags: unity, java, processing

I am making a 3D game with java using the Processing 3 framework. I need the `Mathf.PingPong()` function from Unity so that I can make a bouncing ball. Unfortunately, there is no `Mathf.PingPong()` in Java. Any alternative methods to do this?

Comment: You might want to explain what the expected inputs and outputs of that function are. That way you can get answers even from folks who don't know the function by that name.

Comment: For example, some folks might know this better as a "triangle wave". [Searching that with the added keyword "java" turns up some hits that might be useful for you](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=triangle+wave+java&ia=web).

Answer (score 3):

Unity has open sourced their C# runtime to be used as a reference, so you can go checkout how the function is implemented and reimplement it in Java: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L362

In case the link dies, here is the gist of the implementation you'd need to translate to Java:

```cs
public static float Repeat(float t, float length)
{
    return Clamp(t - Mathf.Floor(t / length) * length, 0.0f, length);
}

public static float PingPong(float t, float length)
{
    t = Repeat(t, length * 2F);
    return length - Mathf.Abs(t - length);
}
```

Comment: Okay! thanks! I'll convert it!